# How to find the endangle for beizerpath for a curve drawn in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have drawn a beizer path with start & end angle which create a whole circle

```
circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height:200))
        circle.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.view.addSubview(circle)
        let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: circle.bounds.width / 2, y: circle.bounds.width / 2)
        let circleRadius : CGFloat = circle.bounds.width / 2 * 0.83
        circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(-0.5 * M_PI), endAngle: CGFloat(1.5 * M_PI), clockwise: true)
```

After that i draw a Curve on that circle & does not fill it full to the circle.

```
progressCircle = CAShapeLayer ()
        progressCircle.path = circlePath?.cgPath
        progressCircle.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        progressCircle.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        progressCircle.lineWidth = 4.0
        progressCircle.strokeStart = 0
        progressCircle.strokeEnd = 0.7
        circle.layer.addSublayer(progressCircle)
```

After that i want to add image at then end of curve so to do that i created another biezer path.But here problem is it should be ended as the curve end.So i am not able to find the end angle for the beizer path based on the endStroke of CASHAPELAYER. Please tell me how can i find the end angle of new beizer path based on the curve end point.

```
let centerPoint = CGPoint (x: circle.bounds.width / 2, y: circle.bounds.width / 2)
        let circleRadius : CGFloat = circle.bounds.width / 2 * 0.83
        let arcStartAngle: Double = 0.0


        let rotationDiff = 360 - abs((0.0 - 270))
        let startAngle: CGFloat = -1.57
        let endAngle: CGFloat = CGFloat(Double.pi * 0.7)
        let bpath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> class ViewController: UIViewController {
>
>     var array = [[CGFloat:CGFloat]]()
>     var midX : CGFloat = CGFloat()
>     var midY : CGFloat = CGFloat()
>     let radius : CGFloat = 100.0
>
>     override func viewDidLoad() {
>         super.viewDidLoad()
>
>         midX = self.view.frame.midX
>         midY = self.view.frame.midY
>
>         let path = UIBezierPath()
>         path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint.init(x: midX, y: midY), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle:2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
>         let shape = CAShapeLayer()
>         shape.path = path.cgPath
>         shape.lineWidth = 5.0
>         shape.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
>         shape.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
>         self.view.layer.addSublayer(shape)
>
>
>         var temp090x = [CGFloat:CGFloat]()
>         var temp90180x = [CGFloat:CGFloat]()
>         var temp180270x = [CGFloat:CGFloat]()
>         var temp270360x = [CGFloat:CGFloat]()
>
>
>
>         for i in 1...360 {
>             let path3 = UIBezierPath()
>             path3.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: midX, y: midY))
>             path3.addLine(to:CGPoint.init(x: midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i)), y:midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i))))
>             //design path in layer
>             if midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i)) > midX && midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i)) < midY {
>                 temp090x[midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i))] = midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i))
>             }else if midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i)) > midX && midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i)) > midY {
>                 temp90180x[midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i))] = midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i))
>             }else if midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i)) < midX && midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i)) > midY {
>                 temp180270x[midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i))] = midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i))
>             }else if midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i)) < midX && midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i)) < midY {
>                 temp270360x[midX + radius * sin(CGFloat(i))] = midY + radius*cos(CGFloat(i))
>             }
>             let shapeLayer3 = CAShapeLayer()
>             shapeLayer3.path = path3.cgPath
>             shapeLayer3.strokeColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
>             shapeLayer3.lineWidth = 1.0
>             self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer3)
>         }
>
>         let tempSorted090x = BubbleAsceSort(array: temp090x)
>         let tempSorted90180x = BubbleDescSort(array: temp90180x)
>         let tempSorted180270x = BubbleDescSort(array: temp180270x)
>         let tempSorted270360x = BubbleAsceSort(array: temp270360x)
>
>         for item in tempSorted090x {
>             array.append(item)
>         }
>         for item in tempSorted90180x {
>             array.append(item)
>         }
>         for item in tempSorted180270x {
>             array.append(item)
>         }
>         for item in tempSorted270360x {
>             array.append(item)
>         }
>
>         let lbl = UILabel()
>         lbl.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)
>         lbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
>         lbl.layer.cornerRadius = 15
>
>
>         for i in 1...180 {
>             let xpos = Array(array[i-1].keys)[0]
>             let ypos = Array(array[i-1].values)[0]
>
>             let xpos1 = Array(array[i].keys)[0]
>             let ypos1 = Array(array[i].values)[0]
>
>             let path3 = UIBezierPath()
>             path3.move(to: CGPoint.init(x: xpos, y: ypos))
>             path3.addLine(to:CGPoint.init(x: xpos1, y:ypos1))
>             let shapeLayer3 = CAShapeLayer()
>             shapeLayer3.path = path3.cgPath
>             shapeLayer3.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
>             shapeLayer3.lineWidth = 5.0
>             self.view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer3)
>
>
>         }
>         lbl.center = CGPoint.init(x: Array(array[180].keys)[0], y: Array(array[180].values)[0])
>         self.view.addSubview(lbl)
>     }
>
>     func BubbleDescSort(array : [CGFloat:CGFloat]) -> [[CGFloat:CGFloat]] {
>         var sortedArray = Array(array.keys)
>         var sortedvalueArray = Array(array.values)
>         var sortedAboveIndex = sortedArray.count-1 // Assume all values are not in order
>         repeat {
>             var lastSwapIndex = 0
>
>             for i in 1...sortedAboveIndex{
>                 if (sortedArray[i] as AnyObject) as! CGFloat > (sortedArray[i - 1] as AnyObject) as! CGFloat  {
>                     sortedArray.swapAt(i, i-1)
>                     sortedvalueArray.swapAt(i, i-1)
>                     lastSwapIndex = i
>                 }
>             }
>             sortedAboveIndex = lastSwapIndex
>
>         } while (sortedAboveIndex != 0)
>         var index = 0
>         var arr = [[CGFloat:CGFloat]]()
>         for item in sortedArray {
>             var dic = [CGFloat:CGFloat]()
>             dic[item] = sortedvalueArray[index]
>             arr.append(dic)
>             index += 1
>         }
>         return arr
>     }
>
>     func BubbleAsceSort(array : [CGFloat:CGFloat]) -> [[CGFloat:CGFloat]] {
>         var sortedArray = Array(array.keys)
>         var sortedvalueArray = Array(array.values)
>         var sortedAboveIndex = sortedArray.count-1 // Assume all values are not in order
>         repeat {
>             var lastSwapIndex = 0
>
>             for i in 1...sortedAboveIndex{
>                 if (sortedArray[i - 1] as AnyObject) as! CGFloat > (sortedArray[i] as AnyObject) as! CGFloat {
>                     sortedArray.swapAt(i, i-1)
>                     sortedvalueArray.swapAt(i, i-1)
>                     lastSwapIndex = i
>                 }
>             }
>             sortedAboveIndex = lastSwapIndex
>
>         } while (sortedAboveIndex != 0)
>         var index = 0
>         var arr = [[CGFloat:CGFloat]]()
>         for item in sortedArray {
>             var dic = [CGFloat:CGFloat]()
>             dic[item] = sortedvalueArray[index]
>             arr.append(dic)
>             index += 1
>         }
>         return arr
>     }
>
>     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
>         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
>         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
>     }
>
>
> }
> ```

**In this code you need to Set Progress Percentage based on the 360 degree. in the upper limit of for loop and Round lbl Center point x and y pos. Here is need only 180 replace to your progress percentage**

Comment: Why 2 * pi as end angle depend upon the progress made by cashapelayer which is in red color

Comment: Progressvalue * .pi that is your second angle. Here 0 to 2 * pi is full circle.

Comment: This value in not correct as it should be same as the red shape layer

Comment: i got the solution for your problem. @DhirajKumar

Comment: Please post the answer if it works for me then i will accept it answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158946/discussion-between-dhiraj-kumar-and-vishal-patel).

Comment: I don't want to run a loop can you answer in context of my question